# Why does Clang prefer the primary template over the specialization from C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization

The following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/f43EK4PnY) is reduced from the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740188):

```
template <typename T, void (*)(T), typename = void>  
struct S;

template <typename T, void (*f)(T)>
struct S<T, f, void> {};

S<int const, nullptr> s;
```

In all versions of GCC, in all language revisions, the specialization of `S` is chosen when `s` is instantiated.

In all versions of Clang, but only from C++17 onward, the primary template is chosen when instantiating `s`.

Some points I think worth noting are that the primary is never chosen if the instantiation is over `<int, nullptr>`, i.e. the first parameter is no longer `int const`. Also, the primary is never chosen if the signature of the function pointer in the second parameter doesn't contain `T` as the argument, i.e. if the second parameter is `T (*)()`, or `void (*)()`, say.

If this code isn't IFNDR, which compiler is correct? Is there some breaking change in the C++17 language revision?

Comment: The difference between primary template and specialization is for the third parameter... which is `void` anyway. so clang bug or ILNDR IMO.

Comment: Maybe helpful to analyze that in detail: tried insightc++ (clang-based) with an attempt of a more minimal scenario (removed the default parameter). Compilation fails for C++17 but not before: https://cppinsights.io/s/da6745e4  I do not see any kind of ill-formed code there nor I understand the error message, that there is no real specialization.

Comment: PS: At least my reduced issue is a bit related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779059/clang-wont-compile-a-template-specialization-that-gcc-will

Comment: [\[temp.class.spec.match\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.class.spec.match#3) (C++14) was removed in C++17 ([\[temp.class.spec.match\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec.match)) as part of [P0127R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html), noting it as "superfluous"; maybe Clang took an action on this. Either way, were I to speculate, this arguably relates to P0127R2 an its changes to the ever-confusing partial ordering rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because C++17 allowed a template type argument to be deduced from the type of a non-type argument. [[temp.deduct.type]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#13):

> When the value of the argument corresponding to a non-type template
> parameter `P` that is declared with a dependent type is deduced from
> an expression, the template parameters in the type of `P` are deduced
> from the type of the value.

So when we try to match `S<int const, nullptr>` against the partial specialization, we deduce the partial specialization's template parameter `T` from two sources:

- From the first template argument `int const`, we deduce `T` = `int const`
- From the second template argument (which has type `void (*)(int)` because the top-level cv-qualification of function parameters are adjusted away), we deduce `T` = `int`.

Since we deduced conflicting results, the deduction fails and the partial specialization is not a match.

Similar examples were brought up on the core reflector back in 2019. There was some agreement that this was a defect in the standard, and that deduction from the type of a non-type template argument should only happen for things that are not otherwise deducible.

Comment: Addendum/extra: [\[diff.cpp14.temp\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/diff.cpp14.temp) was added as part of [P0127R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html) that this update to [temp.deduct.type] was actually a breaking change (although the example therein could arguably have included the more opaque case of conflicting deduction results, as compared to overload resolution now finding another function).

Comment: Great that you pointed out that top-level-cv qualifiers of parameters are not part of a function's signature (good to see with insightc++ for instance)! But why is this not a compile error then? Part/Consequence of the defect? This rule is the same for the base template and should not affect the partial specialization itself (another category of matching look-up).

Comment: So even given the premise, that the non-type parameter with a dependent type "dependency" leads to a special questionable deduction scheme, one might ask why the specialization is not chosen since the first template argument type is still explicitly provided and for the second one, the rule for top-level qualifiers applies to the base template as well and should prefer the specialization since it's really more specialized than the base template given this premise. So non-formally said: IMO, the specialization doesn't introduce a further ambiguity/conflict here actually.Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Secundi No deduction is performed to decide whether the primary template is used. It's used if no partial (and explicit) specialization is a match.